# ターミナル起動時に発生するエラーについて

Tags: macos, zsh

こんにちは。

いつから出ているのかがわからないのですが、ターミナルを起動させるとログイン日時の後に

```
(eval):1: parse error near `()'
```

のエラーが出てくるようになりました。

環境はmacOS Big Sur 11.2.3です。

多分Pythonを使える環境を整えようとしたときに誤ったコードなどをどこかに入力してしまったのだと考えられます。

エラーを無視していれば不自由なくターミナルを使うことができます。

ほとんど知識がない中で環境構築をしてしまい、こうなってしまって反省しています。

原因をご存じの方、何をして直せば良いのかご回答いただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: 参考: [(eval):1 parse error near 'then'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473868/)

Comment: みなさま解答ありがとうございます。解決いたしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

設定ファイルみないとなんとも言えないですが、pyenvかなと思ったのでもし入れているなら[ここ](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation)を見つつzshrcに記述するものを書き直す等すれば良いかなと思います。（`eval "$(pyenv init -)"`の項）
（違うようならすみません）

Answer (score -1):

.bashrc あるいは.bash_profileの記述でエラーが有るのでは